# Setting Checkbox Options C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, checkbox

I've got the following code, written in C++, and instead of there being one single checkbox saying "Show Title", I want to be able to pass multiple strings for different/more checkboxes. How can I give the CreateWindowW function multiple strings for multiple checkboxes? And should the CreateWindowW function be modified in the Select function or the WndProc function?

```
void Select(vector<string>& ret)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL; //NULL = the current process
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    MSG  msg;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Check Box";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Check Box",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        150, 150, 230, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    //return (int)msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    bool checked = true;

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Show Title",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
            20, 20, 185, 35, hwnd, (HMENU)1,
            NULL, NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
        if (checked) {

            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
            SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"");
        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"Check Box");
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

EDIT: Here's the new code

```
void columnSelect(vector<string>& ret)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL; //NULL = the current process
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    MSG  msg;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Check Box";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Check Box",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        150, 150, 230, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, &ret);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    //return (int)msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    bool checked = true;

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_CREATE: {
        LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
        vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);
        for (int i = 0; i != strings->size(); i++)
        {
            CreateWindowA("button", (*strings)[i].c_str(),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
                20, 20, 185, 35, hwnd, (HMENU)1,
                NULL, NULL);
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
        }


        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
        if (checked) {

            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
            SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"");
        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"Check Box");
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: {

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I give the `CreateWindowW` function multiple strings for multiple checkboxes?

`CreateWindow()` can only create 1 window/control per call.  You will have to manually split up the strings and then call `CreateWindow()` separately for each individual checkbox.

Assuming your `vector<string>` contains the checkbox strings, you can pass the `vector` to your window via the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow()`, and then access it in your `WM_CREATE` message handler, eg:

```
void Select(vector<string>& ret)
{
    ...
    CreateWindowW(..., &ret);
    ...
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
            vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);
            // use strings as needed ...
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```